# How can I display only the post titles from a selected category in columns?

Tags: custom-field, list, columns

I'm working on a website where the client wants a static page displaying information about a certain category. Then under the static information she wants all the posts from that category in a 2 column list.

So I need to have an alphabetically ordered list linking to all the post in a selected category. I have the code to do this, but I need to be able to break the list up in columns.
Here is the code I have displaying the post...

```
<?php
if (is_page() ) {
$category = get_post_meta($posts[0]->ID, 'category', true);
}
if ($category) {
  $cat = get_cat_ID($category);
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $post_per_page = -1; // -1 shows all posts
  $do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
  $args=array(
    'category__in' => array($cat),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'caller_get_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies
  );
  $temp = $wp_query;  // assign orginal query to temp variable for later use   
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
  if( have_posts() ) : 
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <_li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to          <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><_/li>
```

I know my HTML skills aren't the best, but here is the entire template page...

https://gist.github.com/889340

Comment: Looks like the HTML in your example is a bit mangle: `id="post">` is off by itself. Can you update your question to show the full code for your HTML generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer:**
Use two floated lists to emulate columns, same approach as previously though.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: PageOfPosts
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <div class="t">
        <div class="b">
            <div class="l">
                <div class="r">
                    <div class="bl">
                        <div class="br">
                            <div class="tl">
                                <div class="tr">
                                    <div class="pad">

                                        <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                        <?php 
                                        $category = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'category', true); 
                                        $img_style = 'style="width:606;height:34;position: absolute; padding-top:1px; padding-left: 2px; z-index:9999; background: no-repeat;"';
                                        ?>

                                        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                            <img src="../wp-content/themes/DD4L/images/leafhr.png" <?php? echo $img_style;?>>
                                            <br />

                                            <div class="entry">
                                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
                                            </div>

                                            <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

                                        </div>

                                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                                        <br /><br />

                                        <?php if( !empty( $category ) ) : ?>

                                        <?php
                                        $args = array(
                                            'orderby' => 'title',
                                            'order' => 'asc',
                                            'nopaging' => true,
                                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                    'terms' => array( $category ),
                                                    'field' => 'slug'
                                                )
                                            )
                                        );
                                        $category_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                                        ?>

                                        <?php if( $category_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>

                                        <?php
                                        $total = $category_query->post_count;
                                        $quart = $total / 4;

                                        if( floor( $quart ) != $quart )
                                            $quart = ceil( $quart );
                                        $counter = 0;
                                        ?>

                                        <div class="float-container">
                                            <ul class="alignleft">
                                            <?php while( $category_query->have_posts() ) : $category_query->the_post(); $counter++; ?>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                </li>

                                            <?php if( $quart == $counter ) : $counter = 0; ?>
                                            </ul>

                                            <ul class="alignleft">
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                                            </ul>

                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

See edit revision for previous comments and code.

Comment: @t310s: You are my hero!!! That works great, but there is just one thing. How can have the alphabetical order to be vertical instead of horizontal? Thanks a lot man, this is exactly what I needed. I've looked everywhere for this thing!

Comment: @Daymon - That's exactly what i was referring to when i mentioned not knowing what structure you had in mind, it will need some adjustment to have results listed vertically instead. I'll update the answer shortly, just gotta have a think about how to refactor the code.. :)

Comment: @Daymon - Answer updated.. Opted for using the table still but using DIVs as virtual table cells. If you need help creating CSS to pretty up the results, let me know.

Comment: @t31os - You're awesome! That listed it in vertical alphabetical order but how do i split into two columns? Could I do 2 separate lists instead of using the DIV tag? Then just float it to the left with whatever width?

Comment: You should have two columns already, the second half of results should list out inside a second table column, is that not happening?

Comment: @t31os No it's just in one column.

Comment: Can you view source and copy->paste the output into a > [pastie](http://www.pastie.org) < please, then report the link back here for me, so i can check the output.

Comment: @t31os [link]http://www.pastie.org/1726442

Comment: Update this line `$total = $category_query->found_posts;
` to `$total = $category_query->post_count;` and see if that clears up the problem.

Comment: Badabing! Thanks a lot man! I think I can get it from here. I would love to add you on skype so I can bug you again sometime. :)

Comment: You're welcome... :) The quick CSS fix would be something like `height:50px;max-height:50px` on the div elements that wrap each result, they'll then look more like table cells (setting 50% width on the two table columns would probably help to)... :)

Comment: Ya know, we could actually drop the table and do it with two floating lists instead if you want, the approach is pretty much the same.

Comment: I think I would like the list better, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: No problem, i only went with the table first off because i was assuming a structure like i initially posted, i'll update the answer with new code shortly.. ;)

Comment: How hard would it be to add 2 more columns? If its too much, don't worry about it.

Comment: Wouldn't be too hard, you'd have to do some calculations in PHP to work out when to split results, but definately possible. I'll see about providing an example later this evening, in the mean time there's an updated example using lists added to my answer... :)

Comment: Was easier than i thought, updated answer to use 4 columns. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without really looking at your code and just thinking off the top of my head you could set up a new WP-Query for each column.

In your args set 'posts_per_page' => 10, or however many post permalinks you want to show in each column.  Assign a  ul or div class to the columns and float them left in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the List Category plugin which will let you insert shortcode into any page or post to show either matching posts by categories or by tags. You can specify order sorting, hide/show excerpts, and much more.

Download:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/

List of full commands:
http://foro.picandocodigo.net/discussion/251/list-category-posts-documentation/